# SQL Error, Warning: `oci_execute()`: ORA-00996: the concatenate operator is ||, not | in C:\wa

Tags: php, sql, oracle, concatenation

I work to execute this sql

```
$tarifekatalogcwsql=oci_parse($conn,'select TARIFE_ID, HIZMET_TURU, ALT_HIZMET_TURU, KAYIT_TARIHI, OM_TARIFE_ID from SMARTTBILL.TARIFE_KATALOG_CW 
        WHERE HIZMET_TURU='.$rowisemriabonecw[0].' AND ALT_HIZMET_TURU='.$rowisemriabonecw[1].' AND OM_TARIFE_ID='.$rowisemriabonecw[4].'');
```

You can just consider sql statement. When I execute this query, it returns error which I wrote in the header.

In my db tables, I have some values that includes '|' character and because of this, system gave me such an error.

`OM_TARIFE_ID='.$rowisemriabonecw[4].'` this is the source of the problem. 
`OM_TARIFE_ID='1|1'`
`$rowisemriabonecw[4]='1|1'`
both are same but the system considers the '|' character as concatenation string.

Can you help for that case? How can I deal with the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$tarifekatalogcwsql=oci_parse(
    $conn,
    'select TARIFE_ID, HIZMET_TURU, ALT_HIZMET_TURU, KAYIT_TARIHI, OM_TARIFE_ID from SMARTTBILL.TARIFE_KATALOG_CW WHERE '
    .'HIZMET_TURU = "' . $rowisemriabonecw[0] . '" AND '
    .'ALT_HIZMET_TURU = "' . $rowisemriabonecw[1] . '" AND '
    .'OM_TARIFE_ID = "' . $rowisemriabonecw[4] . '"'
);
```

But Your approach is the simplest way to make **SQL Injection!**

### This is correct approach:

```
$tarifekatalogcwsql=oci_parse(
    $conn,
    'SELECT TARIFE_ID, HIZMET_TURU, ALT_HIZMET_TURU, KAYIT_TARIHI, OM_TARIFE_ID '
    .' FROM SMARTTBILL.TARIFE_KATALOG_CW '
    .'WHERE HIZMET_TURU = :HIZMET_TURU '
    .'  AND ALT_HIZMET_TURU = :ALT_HIZMET_TURU '
    .'  AND OM_TARIFE_ID = :OM_TARIFE_ID'
);

oci_bind_by_name($tarifekatalogcwsql, ":HIZMET_TURU", $rowisemriabonecw[0]);
oci_bind_by_name($tarifekatalogcwsql, ":ALT_HIZMET_TURU", $rowisemriabonecw[1]);
oci_bind_by_name($tarifekatalogcwsql, ":OM_TARIFE_ID", $rowisemriabonecw[4]);
```

Documentation: [oci-bind-by-name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php)

Comment: I dont need sql injection, because it is a small help tool for me and db user has just read privilege. Thank you for help, it works great.

Comment: @MehmetAkifGüzey Read permission can also give access to other, possibly dangerous info. Best practice is to use correct pattern __ALWAYS__